# How to manage two JRadioButtons in java so that only one of them can be selected at a time

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

How to manage two JRadioButtons in java so that only one of them can be selected at a time? Is there any method in java to take care of this or you need to build your own logic?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have to add them in a [ButtonGroup](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton)

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(birdButton);
group.add(catButton);
```

Ensure you add this code after the buttons are created using the new `JRadioButton` constructors, as appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

My java is rusty but if i remember correctly you have to use the ButtonGroup class.
Add your radio buttons to ButtonGroup object. I think it will look like this.

```
ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
buttonGroup.add(new JRadioButton('Label', false));
buttonGroup.add(new JRadioButton('Label2', true));
```

Hope this helps. I have abandoned Java years ago.

Comment: But then how to add them to JPanel because add method does not work for ButtonGroup

Comment: You still need to add the JRadioButtons to the JPanel individually; the ButtonGroup is merely a construct used to maintain the selected state of the buttons; it is not a layout component.

Comment: sorry to bother, I figured it out in the meantime.
It was exactly the way you said Adamski.
Thank you.